# JSON objects being returned from Express API with quotes -- why? and how to resolve?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I know this is a silly error on my part, but I'm scratching my head trying to see where I'm going wrong.  I've written MERN stack apps before and not encountered this: that my JSON data is being returned wrapped in double quotes.

On the server side I'm reading in a file (with `fs.readFile`) with a format like this

```
{"projects":[
  {
    "project1": {
      "title": "something",
      "date": "sometime",
      "text": "some stuff",
      "img": "some url"
    }
  }
]}
```

and serving it thusly

```
router.get('/projects', function (req, res) {
    logic.getProjects()
        .then(projects => res.json(projects))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

On the client side I fetch it

```
 getProjects() {
        return fetch('/api/projects',{ headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

but what my React app receives is

```
"   {"projects":[
      {
        "project1": {
          "title": "something",
          "date": "sometime",
          "text": "some stuff",
          "img": "some url"
        }
      }
    ]} "
```

That is, it's surrounded in double quotes even though -- as I understand it -- it's already been parsed.  If anyone could point me to my (surely obvious to everyone except to me) error, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: you have to parse the response through JSON.parse()

Comment: You should return something to the user in the catch block, otherwise the browser will wait till the timeout: `res.status(500).send('Something broke!')` see here: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

readFile returns a string.  you will need to `JSON.parse(readFile)` and send that.

Your route would need to be somethign like

```
router.get('/projects', function (req, res) {
    logic.getProjects()
        .then(projects => JSON.parse(projects))
        .then(jsonProjects => res.json(jsonProjects))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
```